# how to solve issue running podman run ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, podman

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on wsl 1. I have installed podman. After pulling the image when tried to run it got the following error `unable to write pod event "write unixgram @00044->/run/systemd/journal/socket: sendmsg: no such file or directory"`

and `cannot create a new network namespace: "permission denied"`

How to solve this issue?

Comment: A [Podman GitHub issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/4325) talks about a similar error message. I'm not sure it is related though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://askubuntu.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  Container systems like Docker and Podman that manipulate namespaces and cgroups will not run on WSL1.  You'll need WSL2 in order to run Podman.

More Detail:

While WSL1 is great at running many types of Linux binaries, it does so by acting as a "translation layer", mapping Linux kernel syscalls to the rough equivalent in the Windows kernel.  However, it does *not* provide a real Linux kernel, and its abilities do not include the namespace support needed for containers.

You'll definitely need WSL2, which runs in a VM with a real Linux kernel, in order to use Podman, or any other Linux container technology.